# DataGridView: Pasting into multiple cells of a sorted data-bound DGV

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DGV bound to a DataTable. I'm relying on the default sorting mechanism that orders rows upon a click on a column header. I have a handler for Ctrl+V implemented that stores a previously captured value into ALL currently selected cells. Everything works fine except for one very annoying case.

If my selection for pasting includes a column that DGV is currently sorted upon, it messes up the order of rows. Even the previously sorted row does not appear to be properly sorted until I force sorting by clicking on the column header.

How can I avoid this?

I tried to disable the sorting of the DataTable.DefaultView associated with the DGV before changing the cells. It did not help.

I tried to force the re-sorting after I finish pasting. Did not work as expected either.

Pasting into non-sorted columns works fine.

Am I even approaching the problem from the right angle? What is the right way to paste/update cells that belong to a sorted column of a DGV?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "messes up the order of the rows"? It seems to be a given that if you change the data in a sorted list, the list will need to be resorted.

Comment: @igby Imaging that I had 20 strings "SSP" starting from the first row. I select cells in rows 2-5 and paste the value of "NIP" in there. As the result, I get the following values displayed starting from the first row: NIP, NIP, SSP, SSP, NIP, SSP... The order gets straightened out if I navigate away from this column and traverse the misplaced rows. I understand that this is strange. Maybe it has something to do with some kind of incomplete rendering, which completes if I navigate around? I am lost...

Comment: I am also considering to implement the "Apple Inc." approach and to deny the whole paste operation if it traverses the sorted column. Ugly and inconvenient, but consistent.

Comment: That is weird. There must be a way to programmatically force a resort/refresh though...

Comment: @IgbyLargeman Here is ore precise description of what happens. The DGV does get re-ordered, EXCEPT for the current row. Once I navigate from this row, the ordering gets fully restored. I guess, I need to force navigation away from the current row to make things straight...

Comment: Well you can do that programatically. Maybe it's just a repainting issue. Try calling Invalidate() perhaps.

Comment: Did you work this out? The problem that I'm having is the rows are re-ordering immediately after the change while I'm in the middle of the "paste loop".